# tikz calendar shrank/compressed to single day

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar, tikz-calendar

I have a strange error and I have the feeling that the solution is quite obvious...

What I am trying to do is make a simple calendar with tikz. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar[dates=2018-10-01 to 2018-10-last];
    \calendar[dates=2018-11-01 to 2018-11-last];
    \calendar[dates=2018-12-01 to 2018-12-last];
    \calendar[dates=2019-01-01 to 2019-01-last];
    \calendar[dates=2019-02-01 to 2019-02-last];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar[dates=2018-10-01 to 2019-02-last];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I was trying to arrange the calendar such that I have 3 months per row, but actually I have some very basic problem here, as every day is printed on top of each other. The output looks as shown in the image. I compiled with `PDFLaTeX` and `XeLaTeX` (which I prefer) and both give the same results.

What am I missing?

[image: Two broken calendars]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to add an option like `week list`. Having 3 months per row may be achieved with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int((\X-1)/12)+2018},
evaluate=\X as \PX using {mod(\X-10,3)},
evaluate=\X as \PY using {int((\X-10)/3)}] in {10,...,14}
{
    \calendar at (5*\PX,-5*\PY )[dates=\Y-\X-01 to \Y-\X-last,week list];
}   
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar[dates=2018-10-01 to 2019-02-last,week list];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me stress that I have no idea where the additional `1` comes from. Is is possible that Ti*k*Z gets confused when the calendar runs over two years where in the first year February has 29 days and in the next year it does not? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thank you! As I expected: quite obvious ;-). The `1` is just the page number, isn't it?

Comment: sorry, I just realized it's **not** the page number, sorry for my stupid suggestion...